# Hibernate Error: org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from resource

Tags: java, hibernate

When I run the project, it occurs an exception as below. Before I add a view table in Hibernate, everyting got well include the Blame.hbm.xml and others. And it could read the data from database. The exception occurs in ShowOrderDaoImpl.java at this sentence: `session=HibernateSessionFactory.getSession();`

My exception

```
    org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from resource pojo/Blame.hbm.xml
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processHbmXml(Configuration.java:3415)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processHbmXmlQueue(Configuration.java:3404)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3392)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1341)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1737)
    at session.factory.HibernateSessionFactory.rebuildSessionFactory(HibernateSessionFactory.java:75)
    at session.factory.HibernateSessionFactory.getSession(HibernateSessionFactory.java:57)
    at dao.impl.ShowOrderDaoImpl.queryTradesByBid(ShowOrderDaoImpl.java:24)
    at test.testHibernate.main(testHibernate.java:45)
Caused by: org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException: Duplicate class/entity mapping pojo.Blame
ok
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MappingsImpl.addClass(Configuration.java:2580)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder.bindRoot(HbmBinder.java:174)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processHbmXml(Configuration.java:3412)
    ... 8 more
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at dao.impl.ShowOrderDaoImpl.queryTradesByBid(ShowOrderDaoImpl.java:25)
    at test.testHibernate.main(testHibernate.java:45)
```

my hibernate.cfg.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
                                         "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/disputesystem</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
  <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
  <mapping resource="pojo/Blame.hbm.xml"/>
  <mapping resource="pojo/Buyer.hbm.xml"/>
  <mapping resource="pojo/Dispute.hbm.xml"/>
  <mapping resource="pojo/Evidence.hbm.xml"/>
  <mapping resource="pojo/Goods.hbm.xml"/>
  <mapping resource="pojo/Message.hbm.xml"/>
  <mapping resource="pojo/Record.hbm.xml"/>
  <mapping resource="pojo/Seller.hbm.xml"/>
  <mapping resource="pojo/Staff.hbm.xml"/>
  <mapping resource="pojo/Trade.hbm.xml"/>
  <mapping resource="pojo/Fund.hbm.xml"/>
  <mapping resource="pojo/Showorderbybid.hbm.xml"/>
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

my ShowOrderDaoImpl.java file

```
package dao.impl;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

import pojo.Showorderbybid;
import session.factory.HibernateSessionFactory;
import dao.intf.ShowOrderDao;

public class ShowOrderDaoImpl implements ShowOrderDao{

    @Override
    public List<Showorderbybid> queryTradesByBid(String bid) throws Exception {
        Session session=null;
        Transaction transaction=null;
        List<Showorderbybid> orders=new ArrayList<Showorderbybid>();
        try {
            session=HibernateSessionFactory.getSession();
            transaction=session.beginTransaction();
            Query query=session.createQuery("from Showorderbybid where bid=?");
            query.setParameter(0, bid);
            orders=(List<Showorderbybid>)query.list();
            List CountView = new ArrayList(); 
            Iterator it = orders.iterator(); 
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                Object[] all = (Object[]) it.next(); 
                Showorderbybid countViewId = new Showorderbybid(); 
                countViewId.setAmount((Integer) all[0]); 
                countViewId.setBid((String) all[1]); 
                countViewId.setDetail((String) all[2]); 
                countViewId.setGid((String)all[3]); 
                countViewId.setGname((String)all[4]);
                countViewId.setLogistics((String)all[5]);
                countViewId.setSid((String)all[6]);
                countViewId.setSname((String)all[7]);
                countViewId.setStatus((String)all[8]);
                countViewId.setTid((String)all[9]);
                countViewId.setTotalmoney((Integer) all[10]);
                countViewId.setTradetime((Date)all[11]);
                orders.add(countViewId);  
            } 

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }finally{
            HibernateSessionFactory.closeSession();
        }
        return orders;
    }

}
```

my Blame.hbm.xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 2013-4-19 23:02:05 by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="pojo.Blame" table="blame" catalog="disputesystem">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="id" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="dispute" class="pojo.Dispute" fetch="select">
            <column name="disputeid" length="20" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="blametime" type="timestamp">
            <column name="blametime" length="19" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="content" type="string">
            <column name="content" length="1000" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: the exception occurs in ShowOrderDaoImpl.java at this sentence: session=HibernateSessionFactory.getSession();

Comment: Showorderbybid is the view

Comment: Did your original xml file contain extra spaces before <?xml version="1.0"?> ? It shouldn't be there.

Comment: It is format error. I delete the spaces already.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like there is another mapping for `pojo.Blame`. You might had a `copy/paste` mistake:

```
<class name="pojo.Blame"
```

In another `hbm` file.

This

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException: Duplicate class/entity mapping pojo.Blame
```

States that when reached a `hbm` file it already has a definition for a class named `pojo.Blame`.

Looks like in some of this files:

```
<mapping resource="pojo/Blame.hbm.xml"/>
<mapping resource="pojo/Buyer.hbm.xml"/>
<mapping resource="pojo/Dispute.hbm.xml"/>
<mapping resource="pojo/Evidence.hbm.xml"/>
<mapping resource="pojo/Goods.hbm.xml"/>
<mapping resource="pojo/Message.hbm.xml"/>
<mapping resource="pojo/Record.hbm.xml"/>
<mapping resource="pojo/Seller.hbm.xml"/>
<mapping resource="pojo/Staff.hbm.xml"/>
<mapping resource="pojo/Trade.hbm.xml"/>
<mapping resource="pojo/Fund.hbm.xml"/>
<mapping resource="pojo/Showorderbybid.hbm.xml"/>
```

Is a misplaced `<class name="pojo.Blame"`

Comment: You mean where I should paste class name="pojo.Blame" to. Or which sentence should be replaced?

Comment: Yeah, this answer seems the most logical `Duplicate class/entity mapping pojo.Blame`. There is a typo somewhere in some hbm file. You have copy pasted your hbm files and forgotten to change the mapping / table.

Comment: Thank you, however I have checked all of my hbm files, there are correct class name as well as its table names. Hence I guess it is not the copy/paste issue. And before I add a view into Hibernate, my project runs well. I guess the problem in the view table "Showorderbybid".

Comment: Even I delete <mapping resource="pojo/Blame.hbm.xml" /> from hibernate.cfg.xml. It caused the same issue while the table changed to Buyer.hbm.xml.

Answer (score 0):

be sure that you have overrided the equals/tostring and hash methodes in your Pojo

Answer (score -2):

check why the session=HibernateSessionFactory.getSession(); is getting null. That is the reason for the null pointer